# Shortcode return vs echo. Return messes with data URLs, echo does not

Tags: shortcode

I am trying to create add-to-calendar links using shortcode. However when using `return` following shortcode function outputs a broken link. (`echo` does not!). Wordpress documentation recommends using `return` and I am worried if `echo`, even when it works, is the safe way of doing this.

```
<?php
add_shortcode('calendar-links', 'shortcode_function');

shortcode_function (){
  $link = '<a href="data:text/calendar;charset=utf8;base64,QkVHSU46VkNBTEVOREFSDQpWRVJTSU...">Download</a>';
  return $link;
}
```

The output of `return` is as below:

```
<a href="https://localhost/text/calendar;charset=utf8;base64,QkVHSU46VkNBTEVOREFSDQpWRVJTSU...">Download</a>
```

I am assuming the shortcode output is going through some kind of sanitisation, but unable to find a fix for it. Also, if it helps, the shortcode is being outputted using an Elementor shortcode widget.

Comment: Maybe that's because `data` is not in the list of [allowed protocols](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_allowed_protocols/). Try adding `data` to that list per filter. Does that work?

Comment: Thanks @fuxia that works!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @fuxia, adding `data` to allowed protocols fixes the problem and I can happily use `return`.

```php
add_filter( 'kses_allowed_protocols', function ( $protocols ) {
    $protocols[] = 'data';
    return $protocols;
} );
```